# How to run automated tests with SCIP

Tags: automated-tests, scip

I´m new in Scip and trying to make automated testing with Scip.
There is the website https://www.scipopt.org/doc-4.0.1/html/TEST.php but I´m not getting it what to do or doing it wrong. Does someone has experience with automated testing using Scip?

If I want to start a test run using what is given on the website scip replies "command  not available". I guess I missed something fundamental to do. Who has a idea what.

Thanks a lot.

Lukas

Comment: First of all, you should check out the docs for the latest SCIP version 7.0 - you have linked the docs to version 4.0...

Comment: Before I answer, can you give a bit more background on how you are using SCIP? I assume you downloaded the tarball and built it yourself? Did you use make or cmake as the buildsystem? Also, what  commands exactly did you use that give you this error?

Comment: Hallo, aufgrund eures Profils wechsle ich mal auf Deutsch. Ich hoffe das passt für euch. Danke für den Hinweis mit der Version. https://www.scipopt.org/doc-7.0.1/html/TEST.php das hier ist der link zu der aktuellen Version. Leider sind hier keine, für uns relevanten, zusätzlichen Informationen vorhanden.

Comment: Wir würden Scip gerne nutzen, um eine größerer Anzahl an Instanzen zu testen und die Ergebnisse dieser Instanzen in eine Datei zu schreiben und auszuwerten. Also eigentlich Schritte auf der oben genannten Website. Wir haben mit Hilfe von VS, CMake und Scipoptsuite Scip eingerichtet anschließend wird unter anderem 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/max/scipoptsuite-7.0.1     Ausgegeben. Bei der Eingabe von "make" sollte nach Anleitung das Programm kompilieren, allerdings wird zurückgegeben "Befehl ist unbekannt". Woran könnte das liegen?

Answer (score 1):

Reading your latest comment, it is clear that your problem is not with running automated tests but rather with compiling SCIP on Windows in the first place.

There is a small section covering builidng on Windows with cmake in the `INSTALL` file in the SCIP root directory. Another possibility would be to use the WSL integrated in windows to compile.

I would ask you to write your comments in English, the whole point of stackoverflow is that others might also profit from the answers to your question in the future.